# Is it likely I'm being underpaid if a Notice of Filing for my role and title shows a higher salary?

Tags: salary, united-states, visa

In our company lunchroom, there is a posted "Notice of Filing of Labor Application", which states that the company intends to hire a foreign employee with an [H1B visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-1B_visa). The role, title, and annual salary are listed. However, I noticed that although the role and title are the same as mine, the annual salary is about $10,000 more than what I am currently making.

Does this mean that I am being underpaid? Or is it typical for foreign employees to be offered a greater salary than domestic workers like me?  (I have been at the company five years, and have had my current role and title for two, receiving a 3-5% raise each year).

Comment: I'm not sure what the standards are for questions about salary like this (especially considering that it might be primarily opinion-based), so if there are ways I can improve my question, please let me know.

Comment: I think it's answerable :) Question, have you had any raises during your 5 years working there?

Comment: @DarkCygnus Yes, I have had annual raises of 3-5%.

Comment: It might be an upper limit, rather than what is actually offered

Comment: It doesn't mean you're underpaid. But it does mean you should feel pretty confident asking for more than 3%-5% when you walk into your next compensation negotiation.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu Are you willing to turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 4):

> Does this mean that I am being underpaid?

Not necessarily. If any, it means that **you negotiated a lower salary than you could have**.

You mention that you have been given the "standard" yearly raises (~4%), that is done to compensate for inflation, increased cost of living, etc..

If you perform well, and feel that you could be earning more, consider if it's time to ask for a raise (suggested reading: [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1025/73791)) .

> Or is it typical for foreign employees to be offered a greater salary than domestic workers like me?

In my experience, yes it is a thing. It is not rare for foreign people to sometimes be paid more than "local" workers, even if they do the same things as a local employee.

Reasons are many and depend on each company and circumstance, but generally speaking, probably to make the *offer seem more attractive*, compensate for *relocation and other expenses*, and, perhaps, a perception that "people brought from outside" should have more experience and skills and thus should be offered more (not necessarily true, though).